# Text Mining in R | memory management

Tags: r, text-mining

I am using a text file of 160 MB and doing data mining, but seems once I convert it to matrix to know the word frequency then its demanding too much memory, can someone one please help me in this

```
> dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(clean)
> dtm
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 472029, terms: 171548)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 3346670/80972284222
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 126
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
> as.matrix(dtm)
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 603.3 Gb

Comment: Find how to extract the frequencies you want directly from `dtm`? The object seems to exist in memory. Do you really need to convert it to an absurdly large matrix?

Comment: As you can see dtm is a sparse matrix, zero entries are not stored as zeros, this saves memory. As soon as you convert with `as.matrix()` zero entries are filled with true zeros. Hence, try to avoid this conversion and operate on the sparse matrix. What are you planning to do with the dtm?

Comment: Another thing, you might use tf-idf weighting or other weighting options on your terms to discard the unimportant terms. This reduces the size of your matrix significantly.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I want to find most used words and plot the histogram. Let me try the suggested way

Comment: If you only look for the most frequent ones you can discard a lot of terms. You might, e.g., calculate colSums or rowSums (depending if overall frequency or document frequency is more important) and discard all terms not fulfilling your threshold. Using the `Matrix` package these functions should be available for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Vineet here is the math that shows why R tried to allocate 603Gb to convert the document term matrix to a non-sparse matrix. Each number cell in a matrix in R consumes 8 bytes. Based on the size of the document term matrix in the question, the math looks like:

```
> # 
> # calculate memory consumed by matrix
> #
> 
> rows <- 472029 # 
> cols <- 171548
> # memory in gigabytes
> rows * cols * 8 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
[1] 603.3155
```

If you want to calculate the word frequencies, you're better off generating 1-grams and then summarizing them into a frequency distribution.

With the `quanteda` package the code would look like this.

```
words <- tokenize(...) 
ngram1 <- unlist(tokens_ngrams(words,n=1))
ngram1freq <- data.frame(table(ngram1))
```

regards,

Len

**2017-11-24 UPDATE:** Here is a complete example from the quanteda package that generates the frequency distribution from a document feature matrix using the `textstat_frequency()` function, as well as a `barplot()` for the top 20 features.

This approach does not require the generation & aggregation of n-grams into a frequency distribution.

```
library(quanteda)
myCorpus <- corpus(data_char_ukimmig2010)
system.time(theDFM <- dfm(myCorpus,tolower=TRUE,
                      remove=c(stopwords(),",",".","-","\"","'","(",")",";",":")))
system.time(textFreq <- textstat_frequency(theDFM))

hist(textFreq$frequency,
     main="Frequency Distribution of Words: UK 2010 Election Manifestos")

top20 <- textFreq[1:20,]
barplot(height=top20$frequency,
        names.arg=top20$feature,
        horiz=FALSE,
        las=2,
        main="Top 20 Words: UK 2010 Election Manifestos")
```

...and the resulting barplot:

[image]

Comment: @Vineet - I added a complete example using quanteda to illustrate how to generate a frequency distribution of top words in a corpus, using an example corpus that is provided with quanteda.