# R from document term matrix to sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix, memory, text-mining, tm

I've got a big document term matrix (42 Mb).

When I convert it to a matrix it runs the computer out of memory.
I would like to convert it to a sparse matrix rather than a matrix.
this is what I am using at the moment:

```
M <- as.matrix(dtm)
```

The package for text mining is "tm".
At the moment I'm trying to split the dataset in two chunks convert them and reassemble them.

Cheers,

Dario.

Comment: You would use a sparse matrix function rather than the general one (and make sure your data is set up correctly). For us to show you, you need a reproducible example.

Comment: That's the problem the sparse matrix function does not work. I'll provide more information asap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Mining in R | memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414401/text-mining-in-r-memory-management)

Comment: `dtm` is a sparse matrix already. `tm` uses the simple_triplet_matrix of `slam` to represent the DTM. Try loading `slam` before working with your dtm.