# Text mining help in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm pretty new here, I am looking for help with R as.matrix() in the process of text mining the code will be below.

I am working with the 378661 obs. of 1 variable.

```
title_txt <- "H:/Desktop/IST719/titles.txt"
titlefile <- scan(title_txt, character(0), sep = "\n")
head(titlefile)

title.vec <- VectorSource(titlefile)
title.corpus <- Corpus(title.vec)
title.corpus

title.corpus <- tm_map(title.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
title.corpus <- tm_map(title.corpus, removePunctuation)
title.corpus <- tm_map(title.corpus, removeNumbers)
title.corpus <- tm_map(title.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(title.corpus)
tdm

m <- as.matrix(tdm)
```

On the console it is coming with the following error:

***Error: cannot allocate vector of size 466.8 Gb***

When I am using the as.matrix(). I quite lost and I would greatly appreciate help on this issue. Thank you.

**EDIT: macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4 & Memory 16GB**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I note in my answer to [Text Mining in R | memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414401/text-mining-in-r-memory-management/47466115#47466115), each cell in a matrix in R consumes 8 bytes. Therefore, the size of the matrix (in bytes) is number of documents * number of terms * 8. When one converts a sparse document term matrix to a full matrix, the empty cells in the sparse DTM consume lots of RAM.

Based on the data you've provided in the question, there are approximately 165,459 terms in the DTM you're trying to convert to a matrix.

```
> sizeInGb <- 466.8
> docs <- 378661
> # calculate number of terms in DTM 
> sizeInGb * (1024 * 1024 * 1024) / (docs * 8)
[1] 165458.9
```

Depending on the type of analysis you're trying to do, you'll need to either use tools from the text mining package that work with document term matrices to analyze the data, or aggregate to an object that is smaller than the amount of RAM you have on your machine (minus the RAM consumed by the object(s) used to create it).

Comment: Could you suggest me, which tools form the text mining packages that I should use to analyze the data or direct me in some manual of text mining? As I have tried the quanteda and it didn't  work as intended as your example.   **Error in dfm.default(title.corpus, tolower = TRUE, remove = c(stopwords(),  : 
  dfm() only works on character, corpus, dfm, tokens objects.**

Comment: @B.Choi - If I've answered your original question: why am I running out of memory when I try to convert a document feature matrix with as.matrix()?, please accept the answer and upvote. Regarding your question about trying quanteda, please post as a separate question, including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll help you resolve any error messages. Please note that SO is not the right place to solicit general advice on how to do text mining.