# R: ridiculous amount of memory needed for converting dtm to matrix

Tags: r

I have a DocumentTermMatrix object that, according to R Studio, is 196.3 Mb large. I'm trying to convert it to a matrix, and receive the following error:

```
kaggle_corpus <- VCorpus(kaggle_source)
kaggle_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(kaggle_corpus_clean)
kaggle_matrix <- as.matrix(kaggle_dtm)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 616.9 Gb
```

The corpus is 3.7Gb, and the DTM as previously mentioned 196.3Mb. Of course I could preallocate the space for the corpus and free it before creating the matrix. I doubt that it I would be able to free 600Gb on my 16Gb laptop though :)

Anyone has an idea why R needs 619Gb to create a matrix from a 196Mb dtm? It needs 619Gb everytime I run the command, so it doesn't seem to be a random number.

Comment: Hey @David, check out [this question on the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414401/text-mining-in-r-memory-management). TL;DR: R is probably doing what it's told and tries to allocate n (`documents`) x m (`terms`) x 8  Bytes of memory for the matrix.

Comment: Hey @Roman, jep that answers my question, I did mark this one as duplicate. Sorry and thanks for pointing out.